# How to invoke Mac authorization plugin for unlocking the lock screen after screen saver?

Tags: macos, authentication, plugins, authorization

I am trying to edit rules in auth.db to get the authorization plugin to be invoked whenever the login window is going to appear:

1. After restarting the Mac
2. After manual log-out
3. When waking from sleep
4. After the screen saver

The rationale for this is to enable unlock/login without the user typing her login/password manually.

Having modified the system.login.console rule I got the authorization plugin invoked on 1) and 2) events but not on 3) and 4) ones. For 3) and 4) I tried to edit system.login.screensaver rule in a few ways, e.g.:

```
<dict>
    <key>class</key>
    <string>user</string>
    <key>mechanisms</key>
    <array>
        <string>NullAuthPlugin:invoke,privileged</string>
        <string>builtin:authenticate</string>
        <string>authinternal</string>
    </array>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>admin</string>
    <key>session-owner</key>
    <true/>
    <key>shared</key>
    <false/>
    <key>allow-root</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
```

The plugin is invoked on 3) when waking after sleep, but is not invoked on event 4) after screen saver.

How can I make the authorization plugin be invoked after the screen saver?

Comment: Can you describe how you edited the system.login.screensaver rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I struggled with this for some time too (your question helped me out a lot btw, thanks for that!)

Here is what worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>allow-root</key>
    <false/>
    <key>authenticate-user</key>
    <true/>
    <key>class</key>
    <string>user</string>
    <key>created</key>
    <real>426709293.721896</real>
    <key>group</key>
    <string>admin</string>
    <key>mechanisms</key>
    <array>
        <string>NameAndPassword:invoke</string>
        <string>builtin:policy-banner</string>
        <string>builtin:authenticate,privileged</string>
        <string>builtin:auto-login,privileged</string>
        <string>builtin:forward-login,privileged</string>
        <string>PKINITMechanism:auth,privileged</string>
    </array>
    <key>modified</key>
    <real>427141220.594918</real>
    <key>session-owner</key>
    <true/>
    <key>shared</key>
    <false/>
    <key>timeout</key>
    <integer>2147483647</integer>
    <key>tries</key>
    <integer>10000</integer>
    <key>version</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

NOTE:
I used the NameAndPassword Apple example not the NullAuth one, so if you're using this with your NullAuth one from the question, you'd need to change that.

Obviously your timestamps and stuff will also be different. Worked for me with all 4 cases you listed.

I am not sure whether all those mechanisms were necessary, so I will probably clean it up in the future, but for now it works.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I thought nobody was going to answer... But how did you manage to let the user not to type the password and Enter manually with the NameAndPassword plugin?

Comment: I modified the code a bit. The password has to come from somewhere, that piece is really implementation specific. For me, I just hard-coded my username/password because the purpose of my prototype was to ensure that having a custom UI for putting in passwords for the Mac was possible.

You can try accessing a local DB with the information or even attempt to unlock with credentials stored on a server, just a couple ideas off the top of my head. Obviously, there are a lot of security concerns and things at play here to be careful of.

Comment: I was thinking about a possibility to authenticate a user without a password (like with a fingerprint scanner, for example). Maybe I have to store passwords in that case too...

Comment: Thanks, your method worked for NullAuthPlugin also with that: <string>NullAuthPlugin:invoke</string> ! It would not get invoked with the standard for privileged plugins <string>NullAuthPlugin:invoke,privileged</string> for some reason.

Comment: Glad to help :)

One thing I wasn't able to figure out yet was the 'OK' button when you go to the lock screen/screen saver. This thing doesn't work to let you log in even if you put in the correct username/password. If you figure it out, please let me know.

Comment: NameAndPassword worked for me with the system.login.screensaver rule you had posted. Are you sure you have not modified other rules in the authorization database when experimenting with plugins? I was getting unexpected effects while tweaking authenticate and authenticate-session-owner-or-admin rules.

Comment: Nice, I had some weirdo bug where calling 'setEnabled' on the password textField caused it to empty out whenever the SFPluginView buttonPressed: method was called. Thanks for the insight :)

Comment: @fjlksahfob, I recommend that you remove `builtin:policy-banner` from `system.login.screensaver`'s array of mechanisms. In my testing, I created a [policy banner](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202277) that successfully displays when logging in to OS X. However, when `system.login.screensaver` invokes `builtin:policy-banner`, the window it creates is invisible; savvy users can keystroke return to dismiss it, but others simply see a Mac that's stuck displaying a black screen.