# Custom lock screen on Ventura

Tags: macos-ventura, sfauthorizationpluginview

I have tried creating a custom lock screen on Ventura following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563104/how-to-invoke-mac-authorization-plugin-for-unlocking-the-lock-screen-after-scree/56830841#56830841), but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on what is needed to be done?

I tried a few different modifications of the system.login.screensaver, but with no luck.